# How to convert lowercase to uppercase without any change inner elements using XSL

Tags: xslt

INPUT:

```
<title>This is <b>sample</b> ack <i>file</i>: good</title>
```

NEED OUTPUT:

```
<title>This is <b>sample</b> ack <i>file</i>: Good</title>
```

Just convert the letter 'g' lowercase to uppercase without any change using XSL.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This is not a well-defined problem. Please explain what distinguishes the 'g' character in your example.Also state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Comment: I am using XSLT 2.0. After colon (:), first letter must be uppercase. So, please explain it.

Comment: I have edited your question to make the code visible **as code**. Next time, please do it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 you can do:

```
<xsl:template match="title/text()">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex=":\s*.">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="upper-case(.)"/>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVAkJ5g/1

Comment: Without any change in inner elements like italic and bold. Is it possible?

Comment: It is possible if the colon and the following character are in the same text node - see my edited answer. Otherwise it gets more complicated.

Comment: @Shanmugalakshmi I don't see what this has to do with the question above. Post a new question.